# how to apply map function to the tf.Tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensor, tensorflow-datasets

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((images,boxes))
function_to_map = lambda x,y: func3(x,y)
fast_benchmark(dataset.map(function_to_map).batch(1).prefetch(tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE))
```

Now I here is the func3

```
def fast_benchmark(dataset, num_epochs=2):
    start_time = time.perf_counter()
    print('dataset->',dataset)
    for _ in tf.data.Dataset.range(num_epochs):
        for _,__ in dataset:
            print(_,__)
            break
            pass
```

the ooutput of print is

```
tf.Tensor([b'/media/jake/mark-4tb3/input/datasets/pascal/VOCtrainval_11-May-2012/VOCdevkit/VOC2012/JPEGImages/2008_000008.jpg'], shape=(1,), dtype=string) <tf.RaggedTensor [[[52, 86, 470, 419], [157, 43, 288, 166]]]>
```

what I want to do in func3() 
want to change image directory to the real image  and run the batch

Answer (score 6):

You need to extract string form the tensor and use the appropriate image reading function. Below are the steps to be implemented in the code to achieve this.

1. You have to decorate the map function with `tf.py_function(get_path, [x], [tf.float32])`. You can find more about tf.py_function [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/py_function). In `tf.py_function`, first argument is the name of `map` function, second argument is the element to be passed to `map` function and final argument is the return type.
2. You can get your string part by using `bytes.decode(file_path.numpy())` in map function.
3. Use appropriate function to load your image. We are using `load_img`.

In the below simple program, we are using `tf.data.Dataset.list_files` to read path of the image. Next in the `map` function we are reading the image using `load_img` and later doing the `tf.image.central_crop` function to crop central part of the image.

**Code -**

```
%tensorflow_version 2.x
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.preprocessing.image import load_img
from keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array, array_to_img
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def load_file_and_process(path):
    image = load_img(bytes.decode(path.numpy()), target_size=(224, 224))
    image = img_to_array(image)
    image = tf.image.central_crop(image, np.random.uniform(0.50, 1.00))
    return image

train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.list_files('/content/bird.jpg')
train_dataset = train_dataset.map(lambda x: tf.py_function(load_file_and_process, [x], [tf.float32]))

for f in train_dataset:
  for l in f:
    image = np.array(array_to_img(l))
    plt.imshow(image)
```

**Output -**

[image]

Hope this answers your question. Happy Learning.

Comment: @slowmonk - Hope we have answered your question. Can you please accept and upvote the answer if you are satisfied with the answer.