# Mapping numpy/scipy function over tensorflow.data.Dataset

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, scipy

I'm trying to extract certain features of a 1D signal that is windowed using `tf.keras.preprocessing.timeseries_dataset_from_array`, from where I obtain a `tf.data.Dataset` object, `ds` (see code below). Ideally, I'd like to map the feature functions (which use numpy and scipy) over the dataset using the built-in `map` method of the dataset.

However, when I try to do this naively:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sc
import tensorflow as tf

def feat1_func(x, sf, axis):
    x = np.asarray(x)
    feat1_value = np.apply_along_axis(
        lambda vals: sc.integrate.trapezoid(abs(vals), dx=1 / sf), axis=axis, arr=x
    )
    return feat1_value

features = ['feat1']
feature_map = {'feat1': feat1_func}

x = np.random.rand(100, 5)
y = np.random.randint(low=0, high=2, size=100)

sequence_length = 10
sequence_stride = 3

ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.timeseries_dataset_from_array(
        data=x,
        targets=y,
        sequence_length=sequence_length,
        sequence_stride=sequence_stride,
        batch_size=None,
        shuffle=False,
    )

feat_lambda = lambda x, y: (np.array([feature_map[ft](x, sf=1000, axis=0) for ft in features]), y)
ds = ds.map(feat_lambda)
```

I obtain the following error message:

```
NotImplementedError: Cannot convert a symbolic tf.Tensor (args_0:0) to a numpy array. This error may indicate that you're trying to pass a Tensor to a NumPy call, which is not supported.
```

What is the easiest workaround for this issue? Is it possible to convert the symbolic tensors to eager tensors when the mapping takes place?

Comment: can you define `ds` so we reproduce your error

Comment: You need to use tf.py_function

Comment: @NicolasGervais I've added the piece of code where ```ds``` is defined.

Comment: @Frightera I've tried using ```tf.py_function``` but I wasn't able to make it work. Could you provide some more details of how to implement in this particular case or an example?

Comment: Did you try it like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62133974/15019223)? Looks pretty much like your case with `.map` and `tf.py_function`.

Comment: @mhenning I've just tried and obtained the same ```NotImplementedError```. I think it may be because they are using tensorflow/keras operations while I have numpy/scipy functions that internally require numpy arrays, although I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to change the line

```
feat_lambda = lambda x, y: (np.array([feature_map[ft](x, sf=1000, axis=0) for ft in features]), y)
```

to

```
feat_lambda = lambda x, y: ([tf.numpy_function(feature_map[ft], [x, 1000, 0], tf.float64) for ft in features], y)
```

`tf.numpy_function` accepts a function that handles numpy array and handles the tensors of the `Dataset` in eager mode (aka, tensors with real values and not symbolic Tensors).
The `ds = ds.map(feat_lambda)` also ran without errors with `tf.py_function`, but I got errors further down the line when I tried to loop over the dataset:

```
# This didn't work
feat_lambda = lambda x, y: ([tf.py_function(feature_map[ft], [x, 1000, 0], tf.float64) for ft in features], y)
ds2 = ds.map(feat_lambda)
for elem in ds2:
    print(elem)  # here I got an error with tf.py_function, not with tf.numpy_function
```

Comment: I still obtain the same error... I've been exploring and saw some old related issues that were due to incompatible versions of numpy and tensorflow. I'm running on numpy 1.26.2 and tensorflow 2.14.0. Which versions are you running?

Comment: Could be. I tested it with TF 2.13.0 and numpy 1.24.3 (which is the newest supported version for TF 2.13). According to the johnnydep tool (it checks dependencies), TF 2.14 should work with numpy 1.26 ("numpy>=1.23.5"). But both package versions are the absolute newest, so it could be that there are mismatches. The newest scipy version should also with with np 1.26 ("numpy<1.28.0", lol).

Comment: I tested my line with TF `2.14.0`, numpy `1.26.2` and scipy `1.11.4`, and there are no errors. I ran it on Windows, but it shouldn't make a difference for this. Python version is 3.10.11.

Comment: Apparently it has nothing to do with it... I've tried to reproduce the error with the package versions in my local environment on colab and your solution worked fine, so I guess I'll have to look more into it. But the solution works :).